# Converting canvas to PDF crashes browser

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs, jspdf

I am using Fabric.js for working on a canvas. Once complete, I scale it up to the size required for upload since the workspace for the canvas has to fit on a screen and my actual uploaded file needs to be approx. 14,000 px in width and 8,750 px in height. If I create an image, it creates it in a few seconds without issue. When I try to create a PDF using jsPDF, it crashes.

This works for creating the image from a Fabric.js canvas:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                format: 'png',
                multiplier: 20                
            })

 document.write('<img src="' + dataURL + '"/>');
```

And this fails to create the PDF/crashes the browser:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                format: 'png',
                multiplier: 20
            })

            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.addImage(dataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0);
            pdf.save("download.pdf");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your image dimensions, this is simply a too big task to be done on the client side.
As the above solution tried to point out, you need to to this on the server side, regardless of the technology you are using.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I suspected. Any Node.js PDF libraries that come to mind?

Comment: I don't have any experience in Node but given its popularity I guess there are many options out there at a google search away. I have implemented a similar functionality using PdfSharp in .NET.

Answer (score -1):

```
JQuery Code:
First you get active object of canvas the go throw
dataArray.push({
                    "objFlipX" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getFlipX(),
                    "objFlipY" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getFlipY(),
                    "objWidth" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getWidth(),
                    "bojHeight" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getHeight(),
                    "objOriginX" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getLeft(),
                    "objOriginY" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getTop(),
                    "objImgSrc" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getSrc(),
                    "objAngel" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getAngle(),
                    "objScalex" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getScaleX(),
                    "objScaley" : obj_Tshirt_canv.item(i).getScaleY(),
                    "objType" : 'image'
                });
$.ajax({
            url : " ",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                dataArray : dataArray
            },
            cache : false,
            success : function(data) {

                alert("data update successfully");
                hideLoder();
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Not Successfull");
            }
        });
Now crate php file and create object of fpdf like
require ('fpdf.php');
$aaa = $_REQUEST['action'];
$aaa();
function createpdf() {
    $size = Array(840, 990);
    $data = $_REQUEST['dataArray'];
    $width = 280;
    $height = 330;
    $_actualratioWid = 840 / $width;
    $_actualratioHig = 990 / $height;
    $fpdfObj = new FPDF("p", "pt", $size);
    $fpdfObj -> AddPage();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $x = $value[objOriginX] * $_actualratioWid;
        $y = $value[objOriginY] * $_actualratioHig;
        $height = $value[bojHeight] * $_actualratioHig;
        $width = $value[objWidth] * $_actualratioHig;
        $_flipx = ($value[objFlipX]);
        $_flipy = ($value[objFlipY]);
        $imgsrc = $value[objImgSrc];
        $dataTppe = $value[objType];
        $rotation = $value[objAngel];
        $color=$value[objcol];
        $randomString = MyStringr();
        $_filename1 = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "path" . $randomString . ".png";
        if ($value[objType] === 'text' && $value[objval] != " ") {//new code to be imp
            $image_src = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . " path". $randomString . ".png";
            exec('convert -background transparent -depth 8 -size 500 -fill "' . $color .'" -pointsize 70  label:"' . $value[objval] .'" "'. $image_src.'"');
            $fpdfObj -> Image($image_src, $x, $y);
        } else {// work done
            $imgsrc = str_replace(" path", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], $imgsrc);
            if ($_flipx == "false" && $_flipy == "false") {
                $fpdfObj -> Image($imgsrc, $x, $y, $height, $width);
            } else if ($_flipy == "true" && $_flipx == "false") {
                    exec(' convert "' . $value[objImgSrc] . '" -flip  ' . $_filename1);
                    $fpdfObj -> Image($_filename1, $x, $y, $height, $width);
            }
            else if($_flipx== "true" && $_flipy=="false")
            {   exec(' convert "' . $value[objImgSrc] . '" -flop ' . $_filename1);
                $fpdfObj -> Image($_filename1, $x, $y, $height, $width);
            }
        }//end else
    }//foreach
    while (true)//generate random file name when cart is added by user in tool
    {
        $filename = uniqid('AddCart', true) . '.pdf';`enter code here`
        if (!file_exists(sys_get_temp_dir() . $filename))
            break;
    }
    $fpdfObj -> Output($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "path " . $filename);
}//end createpdf ()
function MyStringr()//return random file name
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randstring = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $randstring = $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $randstring;
}
```

Comment: I am not using php, but JavaScript and the jspdf library. Do you have a solution that uses these?